# Look for 100% matches,partial matches and dismatches between python list and list column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, compare

I know how to compare lists but working with unflatten data in Pandas is beyond my skills..anyway..
I have:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"col1":["a", "b", "c", "d"], 
"col2":[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [20, 30, 100], [1, 3, 20], [20,30]]
})
```

I want to compare the `list` with the `df` and `print` rows that contain 100% matches, partial matches and dismatches. Desired outcome is then this:

```
"100% matches are in rows: a"
"Partial matches are in rows: c"
"Dismatches are in rows: b, d"
```

Python 3 solution would be much appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

s = df['col2'].explode().isin(lst).groupby(level=0).mean()

import numpy as np
group = np.select([s.eq(1), s.eq(0)],
                  ['100% matches', 'Dismatches'],
                  'Partial matches')

df['col1'].groupby(group).agg(', '.join)
```

output:

```
100% matches          a
Dismatches         b, d
Partial matches       c
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
###INPUT
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
df = pd.DataFrame({
"col1": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
"col2":[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [20, 30, 100], [1, 3, 20], [20,30]]})
 

#Creating another list to define categorize
cat = ['100% matches are in rows:', 'Partial matches are in rows:', 'Dismatches are in rows:']


#Using lambda fun reading DF row by row and compareing row list with actaul list
#If difference is 0 pick first category from cat list
#if difference is 1 pick second category from cat list
# if difference more than one pick the last category from cat list

df['col1'].groupby(df['col2'].apply(lambda row: cat[-1] if len(set(row).difference(lst)) > 1 else cat[len(set(row).difference(lst))])).agg(','.join)
```

Output:

```
col2
100% matches are in rows         a
Dismatches are in rows         b,d
Partial matches are in rows      c
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Update: Suppose you have `col1 with integer` values

```
.agg(lambda col: ','.join(map(str, col.tolist())))
```

Output:

```
col2
100% matches are in rows          10
Dismatches are in rows         20,40
Partial matches are in rows       30
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try! I am wondering, how would the code change if "col1" were integers? Like [10, 20, 30, 40]. I assume, you could not use ".join()", correct?

Comment: @VáclavPech you can use .join() just you have first convert list elements to str. and than you can.